# Ruby include chain module after class load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation where I have to load my module after load class. Here below the sample code

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def method_a
    puts "Method_a"
  end
end

module B
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def method_b
    puts "Method_b"
  end
end

class Ab
  include B
  def calltest
    method_a
    method_b
  end
end

B.send(:include, A)

Ab.new.method_a
Ab.new.method_b
```

I the above example when I call `method_a`, it throws an error. But if move that line above `Ab` class, it works fine. I don't want to include `A` module in class `Ab`. Could someone help me to call without changing the order of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including `A` into `B`, not into `Ab`? This would work:

```
# B.send(:include, A)
Ab.include A
```

Your code does not work because `include B` is executed and basically all methods from `B` added into the base. One could implement `self.included` callback in `B`, collect all the classes/modules it’s included into *and* update all of them when `include` is called on it’s eigenclass, but it looks like a weird overkill.

*Sidenote:* [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include) is public.

Comment: It's public now, but it used not to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can just include module `A` in module `B`:

```
module A
  def method_a
    puts "Method_a"
  end
end

module B
  include A

  def method_b
    puts "Method_b"
  end
end

class Ab
  include B

  def calltest
    method_a
    method_b
  end
end

Ab.new.calltest
# Method_a
# Method_b
#=> nil
```

Comment: No need to put `include A` in `included`. It should work as a "normal" include too.